# Check if matching image is the same size with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, template-matching

Let's say I have a image of a shelf which is full of items. Somewhere in the shelf I have a box. With a template image of the box I am trying to find the box in the shelf using opencv template matching.

If I found the box in the shelf I need to check if the box is the same size as the box is in my template image, and if it is not I will throw an exception. But I don't know how to check the size of the matching image, I don't even know if it is possible. The image will not always be a box so it will sometimes be curved or blended edges.

So what I need to do is after I find a part of the image which matches the template I want to check if the size of that part has the same size as the template image. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Some questions: is your camera at the same pose as when the template was taken? is your shelf always the same?

Comment: Camera is always the same pose and The shelf is always the same and has the same size. I feel like I could just be counting the pixels in the mathing part but I get stuck when im trying to.

Comment: if you know the size of the box in your template, match it with ECC (cv::findECCtransform), then solve its homography matrix and you will get the size of the box in world units (you will get scale & rotation factors) from template to image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the template matching with the image, you can find the detailed code in the following link [https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html][1]

And to find the size of the matched area, `matchLoc.x + templ.cols  and  matchLoc.y + templ.rows` value can be taken.